# using dropdown menu sql statement not working

Tags: c#

```
protected void btn_search_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            string _var_search = ddl_search_by.SelectedItem.Text;
            string _var_by = ddl_search.SelectedItem.Text;
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from UserProfile Where '"+_var_search+"'='" + _var_by + "'", con);

            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            Repeater1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            Repeater1.DataBind();
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                txt_not_found.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                txt_not_found.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include **the desired behavior, a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers._

Comment: I agree that the question is very unclear at the moment (what is meant to happen? what actually happens?). But also: **don't ever concatenate input values into SQL**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont use quotes in first parameter:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from UserProfile Where "+_var_search+"='" + _var_by + "'", con);
```

even better use paramaters:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from UserProfile Where "+_var_search+"=@param", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", _var_by);
```

Comment: (should also use white-listing against the value of `_var_search`)